# How to set default browser for an add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I am trying to set default browser for the add-in I am using to chrome, but by default it takes IE always. How do I change this

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about a scenario where your add-in generates a new browser window/popup. On Windows, this will always be Internet Explorer.

Keep in mind that for all Office desktop variants, add-ins are hosted within an embedded browser instance. For Windows machines, this is an embedded Internet Explorer instance. For Mac machines, it uses an embedded Webkit instance. When you open a new window, popup or follow a link it will always be executed within that same instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marc. So for Windows machines is there no way  I can make sure  that this  embedded browser is not Internet Explorer instance. because we are facing couple of issues in IE , which are working fine online on Chrome

Comment: I'm afraid that just isn't how embedding works, not just on Windows machines. Browser engines are not interchangeable components that can just be swapped out. It is also important to note that you cannot always control how users interact with your add-in, they could be using Windows, Mac, Chrome, IE, Edge, Safari, Firefox or even Opera. Any add-in, or any web app for that matter, needs to take any differences between browsers intro account.