# Outlook Web Add-In: Change the embedded browser and open browser of your choice

Tags: javascript, browser, outlook-web-addins

I am just developing an Outlook Web Add-In. I suppose that Microsoft uses Internet Explorer 11 which is embedded in the Outlook 2016 desktop client. Is there a possibility to change this to another browser, for example Chrome.

I also open a new browser in JavaScript (window.open) which is again Internet Explorer 11. In this case I want to change the browser too, e.g. Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default browser for an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551469/how-to-set-default-browser-for-an-add-in)

Answer (score 4):

Answer to first question - You cannot change the browser in which the addin is loaded inside Outlook Desktop.

Answer to second question - If you are trying to open a url specified in your appDomains(in the manifest) then it would open in IE to allow communication back to the addin.
If you are trying to open just any random url which does not need to communicate back to the addin and not specified in your app domain then it will open in the default browser (set by the user for the device).

For the scenario where you want communication between the new window and addin we suggest using the displayDialogAsync API instead of window.open. You can find documentation about it here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=outlook&version=v1.5